# How to pass a value from the Sqlite DB to julianday()

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, datetime, select

I need to calculate the difference between two dates represented as TEXT. `julianday()` can do this, but it accepts a literal:

```
select(julianday('2015-01-01 12:00:00') - julianday('2015-01-01 13:00:00'))
```

But if I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "time_u" (
    "time_in"   TEXT,
    "time_out"  TEXT
);

INSERT INTO time_u (time_in, time_out)
VALUES ('2007-01-01 10:00:50', '2007-01-01 11:00:00')
```

how can I do something like? :

```
julianday(time_u.time_out-time_u.time_in)
```

in other words take values directly from the database and subtract them as a date

Comment: You have already asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495311/subtract-a-date-from-a-date-in-sqlite which was closed as a duplicate. The link to the original question contains answers provided contains all the info that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn each date to Julian days, then substract:

```
select 
    t.*,
    julianday(time_out) -julianday(time_in) day_diff
from time_u t
```

If you want something more accurate, you can turn the datetimes to epoch timestamp. Say you want the difference in minutes, then:

```
select 
    t.*,
    (strftime('%s', time_out) - strftime('%s', time_in)) / 60.0 day_diff
from time_u t
```

Comment: Result: no such column: time_u.time_in

Comment: @ibse: that’s because of the table alias. Fixed.

Comment: how do I translate this into minutes? where do I add *24*60??

Comment: @ibse: see my updated answer.